# cat command in bash file

Tags: bash, unix

When I try the command

```
cat text1.txt text2.txt > text3.txt
```

in a bash file, unix changes the file name to `text3.txt*`, where `*` seems to be a special symbol. This problem only occurs when using a bash file.

What is the reason and how can i avoid this?

EDIT: Added a picture of the entry in Windows Explorer. i hope, now it is clearer what i mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/okfHh.png

Comment: Where and how do you see the "DLL-file type"?

Comment: eh, my failure. When i open the attributes of the file in Windows Explorer, it is still a text-file, but below it says "Open with: Windows-Shell-DLL".

Comment: What file system are you doing this on?  Are `text1.txt`, `text2.txt`, and `text3.txt` on the same file system?  In the same directory?

Comment: The file system is ntfs. All files are in the same directory and have the same encoding!

Comment: Please clarify how you're doing this. You say "unix changes the file name", but then you're using Windows Explorer. Most importantly, *how do you know* that you have a file named `text3.txt*`? Are you using `ls`? With what options? (Check for `ls` being a shell function or alias.)

Comment: Your `bash` script has DOS line endings; the special symbol is the `\r` part of the `\r\n`.

Comment: Are you saying that the extra character is *not* literally an asterisk `*` character? Can you copy-and-paste the file name (and show us the exact command you used to get the name)? @chepner: Usually `ls` shows non-printable characters as `?`.

Comment: No, it is not, but i don't know a better way to write it. I added a picture of it in the first post. The command was just "ls" and there it shows me "text3.txt?" !

Comment: I'd be more likely to suspect a garbage character in the bash script file, because nothing there will change the output filename.

Comment: Then I suspect @chepner's comment is correct, and you should filter your script through `dos2unix` or something similar. But you still haven't told us how you're using both Unix commands and Windows Explorer on the same files. Are you using Cygwin? Do you have a shared file system of some sort?

Comment: Yes, it seems like the line endings are the problem. Oh, i am using Cygwin! I should have mentioned it! Can i handle it by using another command at the beginning or by editing in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

You probably look at the resulting file using `ls` with some special options; probably these options are added automatically by using an alias or a shell function, so you do not really see them.  When run with these options, `ls` notices that the file has execute permissions set, and appends an `*` to mark this as an executable.  The "type" of the file has not been changed to DLL or whatever; that is probably a misunderstanding of the colouring `ls` also performs.  (Here I take educated guesses which can be wrong, so don't sue me if this is not the case.)  The file name itself does *not* end on `*`, though.  Directories, for example, will be marked in the `ls` output with a trailing `/`.  This is just to ease reading the output of `ls`.

Try looking at the file using `ls` without options:

```
/bin/ls /path/to/that/file/
```

You probably will not see any trailing `*` then.

Now, why is the newly born file given execute permissions?  This is indeed peculiar and not the normal case.  It can happen if the underlying file system is not capable of storing full Unix permissions, then *every* file is faked to have these permissions by the file system driver (just in case one file actually needs them).

To be more precise I'd need to have more information.  A lot in this answer is just guessing on the little you've told us.

Comment: Sorry for such few informations given. I looked at the file by using the Windows Explorer, where this *-symbol is part of the file name and can be changed manually. (In fact the file type did not change, this was a missunderstanding.) This problem only occurs when writing the command in a bash file, but not when writing it directly in the command window.

Comment: I now rather think as well that the shell script contains a weird character at the end of the line.  Could you please type this in the unix command prompt:  `echo text3* | od -x` and tell us what it outputs.  Maybe we can at least find out what character it is.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to copy content of text1 into text3 and then append text2 to text3??

Try:

```
cat text1.txt > text3.txt    //replaces whatever there is in text3.txt with content of text1.txt
cat text2.txt >> text3.txt  //appends content of text.txt at the end of text3.txt
```

Comment: not so ... `$ cat text1.txt
one
$ cat text2.txt
two
$ cat text1.txt text2.txt > text3.txt
$ cat text3.txt 
one
two
`

Comment: Thanks, but now i got 2 files: text3.txt and text3.txt* !

Comment: That should do exactly the same thing as the code in the question. Do you have some reason to think your version will solve the problem?

Comment: hmm.. that should not happen.. It works fine on my machine..
Try using another name for text3.txt and see if it still happens..

Comment: I am not sure, I was thinking on the lines of alias'ing which might be causing this.

Comment: This problem only occurs when using a bash file, otherwise ist does function normally! Also changing the names did not work.